# When we reduce this $Ax=b$ system repres. by an augmented matrix to row reduced echelon form, why do all components of the $b$ vector become numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, maple

Consider the linear system $Ax=b$ where

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&5\\ 2&4&8&12\\ 3&6&7&13 \end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

$$b=\begin{bmatrix} b_1\\ b_2\\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Let's use the augmented matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&5&b_1\\ 2&4&8&12&b_2\\ 3&6&7&13&b_3 \end{bmatrix}\tag{3}$$

to perform row operations.

I did the calculations that follow in the program Maple.

If we perform Gaussian elimination we obtain the matrix

$$U=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&5&b_1\\ 0&0&2&2&b_2-2b_1\\ 0&0&0&0&b_3-5b_1+b_2\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}$$

My question regards what the reduced row echelon form of this matrix is. Maple tells me it is

$$R=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&0&2&0\\ 0&0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}$$

I can't quite understand the last column. When I do the calculations by hand I get the following as the last column (starting from (4), divide the second row by $2$, then subtract $3$ times the second row from the first row)

$$\begin{bmatrix} b_1-3\left (\frac{b_2}{2}-b_1\right )\\ \frac{b_2}{2}-b_1\\ b_3-5b_1+b_2\end{bmatrix}\tag{6}$$

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maple, but is it possible that the symbols you've used for the $b_i$ had values assigned to them in a previous calculation? If so, the program may just be applying those values. Have you tried clearing your variables?

Comment: I just opened a whole new Maple document and tried the calculations again. I defined $A$, $b$, and the augmented matrix $M=[A b]$. Then I told Maple to compute the row reduced echelon form and it gives the result that is in the original post, with the $[0,0,1]^T$ as the last column. Independent of the program, can you confirm that this result is incorrect? Is (6) correct as the last column of the row reduced echelon matrix?

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on now. Notice that the last row of your reduced matrix only has an entry in the last column. The program is dividing that last row by that value and eliminating the entries above it. Basically, the program doesn't know you're treating it as an augmented matrix and don't want to reduce the last column.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after reaching (6), the program basically divides everything by $b_3-5b_1+b_2$ to get a $1$ in the last row last column. Then it eliminates the entries above it. Ok that makes sense.

Comment: I do get the same result as you when I work it out by hand, by the way. And Mathematica is doing the same thing for me that Maple is doing for you. If you try it with a different coefficient matrix that has full row rank, you won't have this issue. Unfortunately, reducing any underdetermined system with an arbitrary vector ${\bf b}$ and a coefficient matrix that doesn't have full row rank will have this same issue in any computer algebra system, since the last row will always have a pivot in the final column.

Comment: Using the information you provided I was able to generate expected results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Perhaps the full answer I provided can be very useful to users of Maple. The time I took to learn those commands can be used by others.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Is this a new reason to close a question that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think that it should be a reason for closing a question. It is seen often at the TeX Stack Exchange forum.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok, thanks. I'll keep this in mind, as I often provide hints in comments.

Answer (score 1):

User @jgd1729 provided the answer in the comments, and I want to add some information here about what I did in Maple to obtain the expected results.

I was using the command

```
LinearAlgebra:-ReducedRowEchelonForm(M)
```

but this reduced the entire augmented matrix including the last column representing $b$.

To obtain the $b$ that would be associated with the reduced row echelon system I did the following

```
P, L, U1, R := LinearAlgebra:-LUDecomposition(A, method = 'RREF')
```

This command provides the matrices in the factorization

$$A=P\cdot L\cdot U1\cdot R$$

where $P$ is a permutation matrix representing row exchanges, $L$ is the lower triangular inverse of the elimination matrix used to perform Gaussian elimination, $U1\cdot R$ is the Gaussian elimination reduced matrix, and $R$ by itself is the reduced row echelon form of $A$.

We can write

$$R=(P\cdot L\cdot U1)^{-1}A$$

Thus, when we go from $Ax=b$ to $Rx=d$, $d$ is

$$d=(P\cdot L\cdot U1)^{-1}b$$

In Maple, this is

```
d := (P . L . U1)^(-1) . b
```

which gives the result I got by hand

[image]